# git pull shows merge conlict in .cproject file

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, git, github

What is exactly the .cproject file?

I didn't add any new files to my project.

I didn't change any project properties.

Is it auto-generated?

Is it safe to take the remote version if I didn't touch this file explicitly?

Comment: The CDT plugin of eclipse can generate a `.cproject` file behind the scenes.

Comment: It may be that your local eclipse settings are different from the project ones, in which case you probably don't want to accept the new one straight away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this file to your git ignore so it will not be added to the repository.

You can use this online tool for that:

```
http://gitignore.io/
```

or simply edit (or create) '.gitignore' it in your root folder with the following content:

```
.cproject
```

Answer (score 0):

This file is auto-generated, which contains your project setting information. you can use a notepad to open it. Without this, you need to re-configure your project.